# Not being able to install Homebrew

Tags: homebrew

I'm trying to install homebrew by typing **`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`** on the terminal, but I keep getting the following error message:

```
/bin/bash: line 234: ./bin/git: No such file or directory
Failed during: ./bin/git -c init.defaultBranch=master init --quiet
```

I've googled it, but haven't found any helpful suggestions, so would highly appreciate it if anyone could help me here. I'm on a Mac, using Mojave v. 10.14.6
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Download and read the install.sh script to help you debug it. Do you have git installed?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @jarmod. Yes, when I run git --version I get ´git version 2.20.1 (Apple Git-117)´

Comment: For some reason, `USABLE_GIT` is being set to `./bin/git` when the script is run. That environment variable is populated by the script running `command -v git`. Debug the script or investigate why `command -v git` is yielding the wrong thing.